# Element fade effect inside div. How do I implement this script?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, sidebar

I'm trying to implement element fade (below) into my text, but it just doesn't seem to work. I can't figure out why.

This is my page.
http://studentreportrarna.se/JMMHT18/Asfaltsnomaderna/

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".top").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
  });

/*win.scroll(function(){
  scrollPosition = win.scrollTop();
  scrollRatio = 1 - scrollPosition / 300;
  $(".top").css("opacity", scrollRatio);
*/





/*$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollVar = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.top').css("opacity", 1 - scrollVar/300);
})*/
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1000px;
}

.top {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"><div class="title">Fade Away</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing curly braces. To actually change CSS using jQuery, you should write:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".top").css({"opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250});
});
```

Just like a normal CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

Does the result of your / 250 need to be an integer (no decimals), and do you need to specify a "%" after it?

Edit - as an answer. ** Also, you need ":" between the property and value not ","

```
$(".top").css({"opacity": Math.round(1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250) + "%"});
```